# Visual Studio: Build several configurations in one step?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have several Build Configurations of a project that I'd like to run in one step. Currently I have to manually build each configuration (Debug, Profile, Release configs) and it's getting annoying. Is there a command line feature I can use? That would make it "a little" easier because I can just tell the script to build each configuration regardless of the one that's started (I'm already doing this for end-of-build distribution of libs and headers).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use *Build->Batch Build...* from the menu. This will allow you to build/rebuild/clean a subset of all your configurations, or all of them.

Comment: Finally the REAL answer for all these "msbuild for multiple platforms" questions!